# Kivy app exiting on screen change

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy

I'm trying to port my code from the .kv file all to Python (it seems easier for me that way). I've got two screens and I've been switching to the next one using `root.manager.current = "main"` in the kv file. However, when writing this bit in Python code, I've run into the crash of my app. This is the code I have:

```
class CustomScreenManager(ScreenManager):
    def switch_view(self):
        self.current = 'main'

class Intro(Screen):
    pass

class Chat(Screen):
    pass

class ChatApp(App):
    def build(self):
        Screens = CustomScreenManager(transition = NoTransition())

        intro = Intro()
        chat = Chat(name = "main")

        bt1_intro = Button(on_press = Screens.switch_view())

        intro.add_widget(bt1_intro)

        Screens.add_widget(intro)
        Screens.add_widget(chat)

        return Screens

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ChatApp().run()
    ChatApp().screen_manager
```

I've also tried the `switch_to` method but it also crashes the app. What can I do to avoid the crashing and get the expected behaviour? Thanks in advance.

Comment: When the app crashes, are you given an error of any sort? Do your log files contain anything relevant?

Comment: No, it just says "Leaving application in progress..." as usual, even though there isn't a line in my code that should close it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the definition of `switch_view` to

```
def switch_view(self, *args):
```

and add the `Button` with

```
bt1_intro = Button(on_press = Screens.switch_view)
```

The app crashes because in your original assignment of `bt1_intro` `switch_view` gets called (rather than passed to the function), and at the time the screen does not exist.